# Inner static class. Java core

Tags: java

Есть класс в котором заключен внутренний статический класс. Пример кода:

```
public class ExampleUserDetails extends SocialUser {

private Long id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private Role role;

private SocialMediaService socialSignInProvider;

public ExampleUserDetails(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(username, password, authorities);
}

//Getters are omitted for the sake of clarity.

public static class Builder {

    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String password;

    private Role role;

    private SocialMediaService socialSignInProvider;

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public Builder() {
        this.authorities = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Builder firstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder id(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder lastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder password(String password) {
        if (password == null) {
            password = "SocialUser";
        }

        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder role(Role role) {
        this.role = role;

        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toString());
        this.authorities.add(authority);

        return this;
    }

    public Builder socialSignInProvider(SocialMediaService socialSignInProvider) {
        this.socialSignInProvider = socialSignInProvider;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder username(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public ExampleUserDetails build() {
        ExampleUserDetails user = new ExampleUserDetails(username, password, authorities);

        user.id = id;
        user.firstName = firstName;
        user.lastName = lastName;
        user.role = role;
        user.socialSignInProvider = socialSignInProvider;

        return user;
    }
}
```

}

Как мне получить доступ к этому иннер классу, таким методом, как указано в примере кода ниже:

```
ExampleUserDetails principal = ExampleUserDetails.getBuilder()
            .firstName(user.getFirstName())
            .id(user.getId())
            .lastName(user.getLastName())
            .password(user.getPassword())
            .role(user.getRole())
            .socialSignInProvider(user.getSignInProvider())
            .username(user.getEmail())
            .build();
```

В примере доступ к классу получают через геттер билдера, я так понимаю. Но как его сделать? Я уже пробовал создавать геттеры и сеттеры, не помогло и вручную писать геттеры для класса и возвращать новый класс, тоже не работает. Кто скажет, как получать доступ к классу именно таким методом как в примере?

Comment: Это стандартный паттерн, который называется [Builder](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BD.D0.B0_Java), если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ExampleUserDetails extends SocialUser {

    public Builder getBuilder()
    {
        retrun new ExampleUserDetails.Builder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Изменил на `public static class ExampleUserDetails extends SocialUser` и все заработало. Спасибо.